# Hyper-V and Windows Failover Cluster Manager - View available resources per node?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a Hyper-V host with Failover Cluster Manager and 6 VM nodes (hosts). How can I see how much memory and CPU is allocated per node? I want to know what my available resources are to create more VMs per node.

I can't find any way to do this in Hyper-V or in the Failover Cluster Manager. The only thing I can think of is reviewing each individual VM created per node to see what resources they have and cross reference this with the associated node to make an educated guess what is remaining. Is there a better way to find out what resources (CPU, RAM) are available on my nodes similar to vSphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of [**System Center Virtual Machine Manager**](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/gg610610.aspx), which gives you the ability to manage your "fabric", view some basic metrics, provision new virtual machines, etc. We use it in our environment and it fills a gap, but it's not perfect and definitely not cheap.

The only OOB way I know of to get the information you're looking for is to use performance monitor. The statistics in [**this article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768535%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) will give you what you asked for and more. I've used it in the past to look at hyper-v performance issues.

Alternatively, others may be able to suggest thrid-party products that are free or thereabouts offer what you want.

EDIT: I went and did a quick search and the It looks like [**Veeam One Free**](http://hyperv.veeam.com/hyper-v-server-management-reporting-free-tool/) could be a nice addition to your setup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Veeam One Free. I'm not having performance issues just looking to see what resources I have left to allocate for more VMs. I ended up writing a powershell script to get vm static, dynamic and startup ram per node.